# on clicking back button, user profile page open php?

Tags: php, button, browser, logout, back

I am implementing logout functionality in php. When I click logout link the session is destroyed(using unset($_SESSION['user']) and session_destroy()). After this, page is redirected to login screen. I tried this before as a standalone application in php and it was working properly. But when i implemented it in my actual code only half part is working, i.e session is destroyed but back button is showing user profile page.

userprofile.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser']) && $_SESSION['CurrentUser']="")
{
        header('Location:/login.html');
}
else{

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    include('Config.php');
    $UserId=$PostContent=$Visibilty="";
    $Vi=$_POST['Vi'];
    $Us=$_POST['Us'];
    $Po=$_POST['Po'];
    $CreateDate = date("Y/m/d");
    $insert="insert into Post(Vi,Po,Us,CreateDate) values('".$Vi."','".$Po."','".$Us."','".$CreateDate."')";
    $insertresult=mysql_query("$insert");
 if($insertresult)
 {
    header('Location:/userprofile.php');
 }
 else
 {
    echo "problem inserting data";
 }
}

if(isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser']))
{
    $user = $_SESSION["CurrentUser"];
    //echo $user;
}

include("Config.php");
$select = "select Post.*, concat(registration.Firstname,' ',registration.Lastname) as Name, about.ProfilePic from post LEFT JOIN about On Post.UserId=About.UserId inner join registration on registration.Id = post.UserId where post.UserId ='".$user."' order by post.PostId desc LIMIT 5";
$selectResult = mysql_query($select);
//echo $selectResult;
include("refrences.php");
?>
<style>
body
{
background-color:lightgrey;
}
li.hover a:hover i.hover
{
    background-color:pink;
}

</style>
<body>
<?php
include("Nav.php");
?>
<div class="container" style="background-color:whitesmoke;">
 <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">
  <i class="fa fa-share-square-o" style="color:black"> &nbsp;Status </i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<i class="fa fa-image" style="color:black">&nbsp;Add Photo</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<i class="fa fa-file-photo-o" style="color:black">&nbsp Add Album</i>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="UserId" value=<?php echo $user;?>>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<textarea  class="form-control" rows="2" name="PostContent" placeholder="What's on your mind???..."></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="col-md-5">
<i class="fa fa-user-plus" style="color:black">Tag Friends</i>&nbsp;
<i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:black">&nbsp Location</i>&nbsp;
<i class="fa fa-smile-o" style="color:black">&nbsp; Symbols</i>
 </div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="control-label" style="">Share with</label></div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <select class="form-control" id="select" name="Visibilty">
       <option value="Friends">Friends</option>
    <option value="Public">Public</option>
    </select></div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
    <input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
    if(mysql_num_rows($selectResult) > 0)
        {
            while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($selectResult))
                {
                ?>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 well" style="background-color:white;">
                    <div class="col-md-2 thumbnail">
                    <img src="ProfilePic\<?php echo $fetch['ProfilePic']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $fetch['ProfilePic']; ?>">
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><a href="#"><b style="color:darkred;"><?php echo $fetch['Name']; ?></b></a></p>
                        <span><?php echo $fetch['PostContent']; ?></span></br>
                        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">Like,</i>
                        <i class="fa fa-share">share</i>
                        <span><?php echo $fetch['Visibilty']; ?></span>
                        <span><?php echo $fetch['CreateDate']; ?></span>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                }
        }
else
        {
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="alert alert-warning text-center">
                    Nothing to share..!!
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php
        }   
?>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-5">
<input type="submit" value="See More......" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">
</div>
</div>

</body>
<?php
        }   
?>
```

Comment: You need to add some sort of check to each page(or with a framework) to make sure that the user is logged in when visiting a page.

Comment: $_SESSION['CurrentUser']="" is missing a extra =, it should look like $_SESSION['CurrentUser']=="", otherwise you just asign a value

Comment: its good practice using exit(); after header redirect

Comment: I've noticed that some installations cannot use `isset` for checking if an array has a key. `array_key_exists` is a better option in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

How do you destroy the session in your code? If for example you are using another file (i.e logoff.php) then make sure you include session_start(); before destroying the session.

For example:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
session_unset(); 
session_destroy(); 
unset($_SESSION); 
?>
```

Also, your code has a bug on line 2:

```
$_SESSION['CurrentUser']=""
```

should be:

```
$_SESSION['CurrentUser']==""
```